# NVD3.js piechart use in Leaflet control

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, leaflet, nvd3.js

I am trying to add some data visualization to web map I am working on and I am exploring the use of D3, specifically [NVD3](http://novus.github.io/nvd3/index.html). I am using the [PieChart Example](http://novus.github.io/nvd3/ghpages/pie.html) as a test run for a proof of concept. 
I add a leaflet control to my map like this (forgive the bad formatting):

```
var visualizationControl = L.control({ position: 'bottomleft' });
var visualizationDiv = L.DomUtil.get("visualizationContainerDiv");

// ...
visualizationControl.onAdd = function (map) {
  this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'control');
  this._div.innerHTML = result;
  return this._div;
}

visualizationControl.addTo(MapProvider.map);
nv.addGraph(function () {
  var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function (d) { return d.label })
    .y(function (d) { return d.value })
    .showLabels(false);

  d3.select("#chart svg") //div with chart Id and svg container within that div
    .datum(exampleData())
    .transition().duration(350)
    .call(chart);

  return chart;
});
```

The chart will render ok in my control, and the on hover behaviour does register correctly.

[image]

However, when it appends the tooltip to the DOM it appends it to the body instead of my SVG or even the control div.

[image]

It's difficult to tell from this image but this was taken during an on.hover over one of the slices of the pie and it should write out the tooltip on top of the pie slice. Notice the "**One 29.77"** sitting off to the side in the navbar.

I have been poking around the development version of the NVD3 js and found a few blocks that refer to the tooltip container and it looks like it should append it to the SVG container.

I also tried changing the css of the tooltip to no avail.
I don't want to give up on this just yet. Any suggestions, help, ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Using the current versions of leaflet, D3 and NVD3, debugging/testing in Chrome.

**UPDATE**
I did not solve this problem using NVD3 I did, however, end up using [C3js](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3). It also has a pie chart and this played nicely with my L.control(). A word of caution though, (if you try to go with C3) look carefully at how the charts are looking to receive the data that is being passed to them. I had to play with this for while to get them to work.

Comment: You can add a container element with class `nvtooltip` and NVD3 should use that automatically to render the content.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Sorry I don't quite follow. In my view I have <div id="chart"> and in that I have an <svg> element. I added another div with the tooltip class but it gave me some strange behavior when I hovered. It actually removed the content of my #chart div.

Comment: NVD3 looks for an element with class `nvtooltip` to put the content of the tooltip into -- that element should be empty. Otherwise, it will append such an element itself (and in your case in the wrong way).

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, however it doesnt appear to be working. Are you saying to create an html element somewhere in my container div/svg with that class? If so I tried that, and it doesn't work. I also tried making a container elsewhere on the DOM and it still floats out to the left there. I changed the logic in the getTooltipContainer() to select by my HTML element ID and it sill appended to the body. Sorry, I just might not be following what you are saying. Could you elaborate a little more, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, sounds very odd. Could you provide a complete working example please?

Comment: If you solved this issue, Could you please share the working example. Even I am having the same issue.